# pandas make blank line between merges files

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

how can i remove the blank line in line 6 and 7?
it just happens when i merge value 1 and value 2, with value 3 everything is fine.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxvy9.png)

````
ListOri = 'Blocked_Persons_List_original.xls'
NG = 'NG.xlsx'
MB = 'MB.xlsx'


df1 = pd.read_excel(ListOri)
df2 = pd.read_excel(NG)
df3 = pd.read_excel(MB)


values1 = df1[["Unique ID","Name","Street of residence","City of residence","Country of residence","Date of birth","Place of birth","Country of birth","Citizenship","Account number/ IBAN","BIC Code","Source","Notice","Reserve 1","Reserve 2","Amount EURO","Currency"]]
values2 = df2[["Name","Account number/ IBAN","BIC Code","Notice"]]
values3 = df3[["Account number/ IBAN","BIC Code","Notice","Reserve 1","Reserve 2"]]


dataframes = [values1, values2, values3]




join = pd.concat(dataframes,ignore_index = True)

join.to_excel("output.xlsx")```
````

Answer (score 0):

the reason was that df1 is a .xls file and the others a .xlsx file